# unable to install "camelot", "ghostscript" on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a Python 3 environment inside Visual Studio 2017. I have been trying to install "camelot" package, which required "ghostscript" and "tk" (tkinter) packages to be pre-installed. I was successful in installing "tk", but no luck with "ghostscript". When I try to install "ghostscript", I get an error stating-

> ----- Installing 'camelot' -----
>   Solving environment: ...working... failed
>   PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>     - camelot
>   Current channels:
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>     - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>   To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
>   looking for, navigate to
>       https://anaconda.org
>   and use the search bar at the top of the page.
>   ----- Failed to install 'camelot' -----

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated 
P.S- I have downloaded the "ghostscript" executable file and added it to the path of environment variables

Comment: None of those missing packages seem to be Ghostscript, it seems to be complaining about something called 'anaconda' which appears to be something related to Python and R.

Comment: @KenS,Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure how R came into picture here, but all I understood is that Camelot can't be found on the particular anaconda repo, but I have successfully installed them on Spyder without any issues. So i don't understand why it is causing an issue just for Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been trying to install "ghostcript" just as a pre-requisite for "camelot". I visited this website- https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/camelot-py and entered "**conda install -c conda-forge camelot-py**" in Visual Studio's Python environment. And it worked!
**conda install is prefixed to every package you enter**. Hence just enter "-c conda-forge camelot-py " in the python environment tab.